# Python number of elements inside a list

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list of numeric strings, like this :

```
MyList = ['1','2','3 4 5 6 7','33333']
```

I want to check for every cell inside the list the number of objects it obtains. I used len() for every cell but it returns me the string length which is what is supposed to do I guess.
I want for example to get for :

```
MyList[0] ~> 1
MyList[1] ~> 1
MyList[2] ~> 5
MyList[3] ~> 1
```

Should I cast every element to check if it returns a number and if not loop through the cell ? Or is there some function that does the trick ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming all are separated by whitespace you can use  [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
MyList = ['1','2','3 4 5 6 7','33333']
print [len(x.split()) for x in MyList ]
[1, 1, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use split and count count number of items

```
>>> MyList = ['1','2','3 4 5 6 7','33333']
>>> [len(itm.split()) for itm in MyList]
[1, 1, 5, 1]
```

The `split` splits a string at whitespace into substrings:

```
>>> "3 4 5 6 7".split()
["3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there's exactly one space between the elements, this will work:

```
counts = [cell.count(' ')+1 for cell in MyList]
```

And will be significantly faster than the `len(cell.split())` methods.

Comment: +1 for creativity (which can be dangerous, unless you state the assumptions as you did).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to determine the number of numbers separated by spaces in each string. You can split a string by spaces with the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) function. So `MyList[2].split() == ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']` and `MyList[3].split() == ['33333']`. Then to check how long these are, you can use the [`len`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) function. Putting it all together with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) you get

```
counts = [len(number_string.split()) for number_string in MyList]
```

And counts will have the value `[1, 1, 5, 1]`.